# Mi código PHP no se muestra en un archivo .html

Tags: php, html

Estoy iniciando con php (5.5.26), y al poner las etiquetas de inicio de php en el body no sale nada, sólo aparece mi código php como comentario cuando inspecciono con el navegador.

Estoy utilizando MAMP y entrando desde `http://localhost:8888/php/prueba1.html`

Y si entro con un archivo `.php` desde `localhost`, sí lo abre y ejecuta el `phpinfo()` y todo eso, pero desde html ¡no sale nada!

¡¡Ayudaaa!!
Gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

 <?php echo "hola"; ?>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De manera predeterminada (sin modificar la configuración del servidor apache) sólo los archivos con extensión `.php` se interpretan como scripts PHP, por lo que un archivo con extensión `.html` no será interpretado como tal.

Renombra el archivo de `prueba1.html` a `prueba1.php` y deberá funcionarte.

Si quieres que te interprete los archivos con extensión `.html` como si fueran scripts PHP (no te lo recomiendo), deberás hacer uso de [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) modificando la configuración del servidor apache agregando la siguiente línea al `apache2.conf` / `httpd.conf` (a nivel global) o al `.htaccess` (sólo directorio actual y subdirectorios):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo!!! si funciono, con tan solo renombrarlo como dijiste.

Comment: De nada. Recuerda que siempre puedes cambiar la extensión que se interpreta como PHP, pero por norma general todas las aplicaciones esperan que estos archivos tengan extensión `.php`, por lo que modificarlo podría tener consecuencias inesperadas (desde funcionamientos anómalos hasta problemas de seguridad). **Renombrar el archivo a `.php` siempre es la mejor solución.**

Answer (score -1):

Acabo de solucionar el problema que tenia que no ejecutaba el codigo php que tenia en un html. agregue la linea al apache en un servidor local con xampp.
Ahora ... en un server externo , hay alguna forma de que corra el html con php ? no me hace ni el include "x.php";
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340312)

Comment: Claudio, en un server "externo" es exactamente lo mismo que indican en la respuesta, o modificas la extension de `.html` a `.php` o haces lo mismo que hiciste en tu XAMPP pero en el servidor.